# What is the meaning of "Vihitha Karma"?

Tags: karma

I have heard the word 'VIHITHA KARMA" frequently. What is the real meaning of VIHITHA KARMA. and How does one defines it?

Answer (score 2):

Vihita Karma means karma prescribed or commended by scriptures e.g Vedas. The Sanskrit word [**Vihita (विहित)**](http://sanskritdictionary.com/vihita/219272/1) can be translated **sectioned / prescribed / allowed / commended / enjoined** etc. in English. e.g Veda Vihita means prescribed by Vedas.

Here are some translations of verses from Manusmriti that clears it.

> **वसिष्ठविहितां** वृद्धिं सृजेद् वित्तविवर्धिनीम् ।
>   अशीतिभागं गृह्णीयान् मासाद् वार्धुषिकः शते ॥ ८। १४०
>
> 140. A money-lender may stipulate as an increase of his capital, for the interest, **allowed by Vasishtha**, and take monthly the eightieth part of a hundred.
>
> अकुर्वन् **विहितं कर्म** निन्दितं च समाचरन् ।
>   प्रसक्तश्चैन्द्रियार्थेषु प्रायश्चित्तीयते नरः ॥ ११ । ४४
>
> 44. A man who omits **a prescribed act**, or performs a blamable act, or cleaves to sensual enjoyments, must perform a penance.

[Bhagavad Gita 17.5](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?scsh=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&setgb=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=17&field_nsutra_value=5): (English translation by Swami Sivananda)

> अ**शास्त्रविहितं** घोरं तप्यन्ते ये तपो जनाः।
>   दम्भाहङ्कारसंयुक्ताः कामरागबलान्विताः।।17.5।।
>
> Those men who practise terrific austerities not **enjoined by the scriptures**, given to hypocrisy and egoism, impelled by the force of lust and attachment.